# How to initialize an array of custom data type with more than 1 member variables?

Tags: java, arrays, custom-data-type

Arrays of Primitive data types can be initialized like :

```
int a[] = {1 , 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

I have created a custom data type with a code like this -

```
class Student
{
    private String name;
    private int rollno;
}
```

I have created a Student array as given below :

```
Student s[] = new Student[5];
for(int i =0; i < s.length; s++)
    s[i] = new Student();
```

I want to initialize the member variables : name and rollno without taking user input. How can I do that? I want to do something like -

```
Student s[] = {("Sam", 21), ("Jules",3)...}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there's such constructor `Student(String, int)`, then you can try this:

```
Student[] studentArray = {
    new Student("Sam", 21),
    new Student("Jules",3)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Student s[] = {new Student("Sam", 21), new Student("Jules", 3)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply Initialize an array of custom data type by:

```java
class struct{
int data;
String str;
}

// while creating an array ...
struct[] name = new struct[length];

// for inserting data ..
for( int i=0; i< length; i++){
   struct stk = new struct(); // create a new object to be stored..
   stk.str = "Priyansh Gupta from UPES Dehradun";   // declaring the values of the object we created
   stk.data = 2021;
   name[i] = stk;    // adding the object to the i'th index of array
}

// for printing the array
for( int i=0; i<length; i++){
   System.out.println(name[i].data); // printing the data of i'th index of array
   System.out.println(name[i].str); // print the string value of the index
}
```